# How to enable Swap APO in SYSVAD sample driver without enhancement tab in windows 11?

Tags: driver, device-driver, audio-device, apo

For the past few weeks, we've been working with the SYSVAD sample driver. We cloned the SYSVAD driver and successfully installed it on our target machine. However, we've noticed that it's not a real driver meant for actual hardware; it's a virtual driver. This means it can't handle actual playback audio or record audio from the microphone. When we capture the output of the SYSVAD speaker, we see a sine wave because SYSVAD generates a sine wave for playback. The actual audio played is taken from the loopback and saved with the name STREAM_HOSTxxx.wav.

Our goal is to enable swap APO by modifying the relevant registry key but we were unsuccessful. We also tried to modify some lines of code in the swap APO and ComponentizedApoSample.inx file, but this didn't help either.

We came to know about the enhancement tab, which is used to enable or disable the APOs, but this option has been removed.

For enabling swapAPO or DelayAPO, do we need the enhancement tab? Is it possible to enable the APOs without the enhancement tab?

We used EnumerateAPO.exe to enumerate the loaded APOs in the system, but we were not able to find any APOs (Sysvad APOs).

We're currently stuck and wondering if there's another way to load the APOs. If anyone has insights or suggestions, we'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

We have tried modifying the relevant registry and also tried by modifying some codes but that doesn't help